# Why do classes sometimes not get loaded when running .install?

Tags: installation

How do I get them to load consistently?

I have a class

```
files[] = includes/YogaHiveBooking.php
```

The .install file grabs some constants from it.

```
$schema[YogaHiveBooking::BOOKING_TABLE] = array(
```

Sometimes it doesn't work

```
drush dis -y yhivebook // fine
```

Uninstall

```
 drush pm-uninstall -y yhivebook
 The following modules will be uninstalled: yhivebook
 Do you really want to continue? (y/n): y
 PHP Fatal error:  Class 'YogaHiveBooking' not found in
```

I think global variables are fine - defined in the .module file. e.g.

```
variable_del(YHIVEBOOK_ADMIN_EMAIL_VAR);
```

I am using Drupal 7.